# Import file from oracle 18c into 11g

Tags: oracle

I export file from Oracle 18c. I import that file into Oracle 11g. I get error

```
       IMP-00010: not a valid export file, header failed verification
```

Is it impossible to do that ?

Comment: What utility did you use for the export - exp or expdp?  What utility did you use for the import?  imp or impdp?  This error typically comes form mismatched utilities ... if you export with exp, you must import with imp.  If you export with expdp, you must import with impdp.  Even though both exp and expdp produce (by default) a file called <something>.dmp, this is meaningless.  The two produce different file formats, and the 'dmp' is just a name.   BTW, what did you discover when you googled ' IMP-00010'?

Comment: Of course , i use exp and imp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To import a datapump file from a newer version into a older version, you need to specify the parameter `version=xxxx` during the export datapump. The default value for VERSION is COMPATIBLE, indicating that exported database object definitions will be compatible with the release specified for the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter.

```
expdp .......... version="11.2"
```

Then, you can import it into a 11g database.

Take the following in consideration

> Database privileges that are valid only in Oracle Database 12c Release
> 1 (12.1.0.2) and later (for example, the READ privilege on tables,
> views, materialized views, and synonyms) cannot be imported into
> Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1) or earlier. If an attempt is
> made to do so, then Import reports it as an error and continues the
> import operation.
>
> When operating across a network link, Data Pump requires that the
> source and target databases differ by no more than two versions. For
> example, if one database is Oracle Database 12c, then the other
> database must be 12c, 11g, or 10g. Note that Data Pump checks only the
> major version number (for example, 10g,11g, 12c), not specific release
> numbers (for example, 12.1,10.1, 10.2, 11.1, or 11.2).